# Haw can I add variable(value from getter) in router-link path in vue.js (with typescript)?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a button with router-link like this`

```
    <router-link to="summary">
         <button type="button" @click='questionsFinish' class="btn btn-primary" 
                :disabled="!isFinishStepEnabled">{{$lang.message.solution_calculate}}
         </button>
     </router-link>
```

I need to pass the value from getter in router-link like this `

```
    <router-link to="{{getlang}}/summary">
         <button type="button" @click='questionsFinish' class="btn btn-primary" 
                :disabled="!isFinishStepEnabled">{{$lang.message.solution_calculate}}
         </button>
     </router-link>

This is a getter method

 get getlang(): string {
    return this.$lang.getLang();
  }

This is a route

 name: "summary",
 path: "/" + languageParameter + "/summary/"
```

Answer (score 0):

set the router path correctly with a parameter:

```
  {
   path: '/:languageParameter/summary',
   name: 'About',
   ....
  }
```

in your computed get the getter value into the component:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

@Component({
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters(['getlang'])
  }
})
```

then bind the value of getter from computed into your ***router-link***:

```
<router-link :to="`${getlang}/summary`">
     <button type="button" @click='questionsFinish' class="btn btn-primary" 
            :disabled="!isFinishStepEnabled">{{$lang.message.solution_calculate}}
     </button>
 </router-link>
```